# Как передать возвращаемое значение функции в ссылку?

Tags: javascript, html

js - код

```
function urls(){ 
         var newss = SpreadsheetApp.create("ResultSpread");
         var url = newss.getUrl();
         return url;
}
```

html - код

```
<a href = "#" target ="_blank">SpreadSheet</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a id="my-link" href="#" target="_blank">SpreadSheet</a>
```

```
function urls(){ 
         var newss = SpreadsheetApp.create("ResultSpread");
         var url = newss.getUrl();
         return url;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   const link = document.getElementById('my-link');
   link.href = urls();
});
```